# Request body in express.js where body is a value from database

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I don't know how to build code to insert data from html body to database where body is a something what I select from database.

EJS:

```
<% categories.forEach((cat, index) => { %>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="T" name="<%= cat.id %>" id="<%= cat.id %>">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                    <%= cat.name %>
                  </label>
                </div>
              <% }) %>
```

and my js how shoudl it look? (??? - don't know what to write here to get checkbox id's)

```
if (req.body.???) {
    let cat_query = "INSERT INTO `cat` (m_id, cat_id) VALUES ?";
    let values = [
    [result.insertId, '???']               
    ];
    db.query(cat_query, [values], (err, res2) => {if (err) throw err;})}
```

my output when I check some checkboxes:

```
{ '3': 'T',
  '11': 'T',
  '18': 'T',
  topic: 'test',
  messagetype: 'N',
  content: '', }
```

Comment: It depends on what bodyparser you are using. Express does not build-in any bodyparser. Some bodyparsers don't even use `req.body` to store the request body (eg. formidable uses req.fields instead of req.body)

Comment: I use: `const bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
It works when I have checkbox exacly ID name but I don't know how to build JS when my body id in ejs looks like this: `id="<%= cat.id %>"`

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use value and change it from `'T'` to `<%= cat_id =>` and let my input name make constant.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="<%= cat.id %>" name="cat" id="<%= cat.id %>">
```

```
if (req.body.cat) {
    const { cat } = req.body
    cat.forEach(cat_id => {
    let cat_query = "INSERT INTO `centrala` (messages_id, cat_id) VALUES ?";
    let values = [
    [result.insertId, cat_id]               
    ];
    db.query(cat_query, [values], (err, res2) => {if (err) throw err;}) 
    })
}
```

maybe it will be useful to someone

Comment: It works only if there is a more then 1 checkbox checked, it doesn't work if there is 1 checked. Any idea?